# why i am Not able to give current class reference in my recyclerview adapter constructor in place of interface that i have implemented?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-volley, android-adapter

My question is simple, I have created an interface so that I can use it as callback or basically for onclick of my recyclerview adapter items. Suppose my adapter constructor is like this adapter(Context context,ArrayList arraylist,AdapterInterface interface) now I have implemented this in my fragment class, and then used it like adapter(getActivity(),SomeArraylist,this), so I was able to use this successfully and was using it for onclick of views in adapter and successfully performing tasks in overridden method of interface. But But But the only problem is this doesn't work in volleys Onresponse(), it gives an error when I used 'this' as the third argument in that adapter constructor. So I am forced to use anonymous inner class there and override again the same method. But I want to know even though I have implemented the methods of the interface , why this doesn't work in adapters constructor inside onresponse() of volley and works everywhere else when I pass 'this'. And what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah! you can't use `this` there. Use `your_fragment.this` instead of `this`.

Reason:
  When you mention this inside `onResponse()` method it denotes the anonymous inner class of volley.

Comment: Thanks alot bro .... :) i forgot for a moment that volley itself is implemented using anonymous inner class and that the onresponse is just the overriden method in that anonymous inner class. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a reference of a simple volley request:

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, 
new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), list, this);
    }
}, 
new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {}
});
```

When you are using `this` inside OnResponse() method of volley class, then it refers to the anonymous class that was created using the new keyword to handle Response.Listener interface.

Instead, you should use `MainFragment.this` where 'MainFragment' is the name of the class that implements your `AdapterInterface`. As below:

```
adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), list, MainFragment.this);
```

Comment: Thanks mate , i could have accepted your answer too , but i believe i can accept only one answer. But thanks anyway.